# How to make Search box Suggestions to suggest on Specific field in Sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: solr, sxa-search

I am using Sitecore 9.0.1 with SXA 1.7 and Solr 6.6.2. I have added one search box and search result component on my page and selected the *ShowSearchResults* as Prediction and it is showing the predictions based on the title field.

Is it Possible to show suggestion on the search box based on specific field which has data type as Single line text?

I have an "*Author*" field in my template and I want to show the author field values as a suggestion when typed on the search box.

For this I made some config change by following this blog https://tamermblog.wordpress.com/2018/02/20/setting-up-sxa-search-box-with-suggest/

This is my Solr config file.

[image]

Right now I am getting results only based on the title

[image]

Please suggest if I'm doing wrong

Thank you

Comment: https://sitecorejumpstart.wordpress.com/2019/10/06/sitecore-solr-autosuggest-with-template-and-language-filters/

Answer (score 1):

I am using Solr 8.4 with Sitecore 10.1
I have used the following configuration and it works fine. The trick is to define the Field you want to see in the payloadField parameter
Here's my suggester configuration.You can see the payload parameter in this configuration. **title_t**

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
        <lst name="suggester">
            <str name="name">sxaSuggester</str>
            <str name="lookupImpl">BlendedInfixLookupFactory</str>
            <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
            <str name="contextField">_language</str>
            <str name="field">title_t</str>
            <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
            <str name="payloadField">title_t</str>
            <str name="buildOnStartup">true</str>
        </lst>
    </searchComponent>
    <requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy" >
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="suggest.dictionary">sxaSuggester</str>
            <str name="suggest">true</str>
            <str name="suggest.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
            <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
            <str name="suggest.collate">true</str>
        </lst>
        <arr name="components">
            <str>suggest</str>
        </arr>
    </requestHandler>
```

I am getting suggestions as value of title field as I want title field to be fetched in the suggestions.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/11906)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Updated the response with an answer in the form of a solution